# Access multiple API's with one token in Kong using the OAuth2 plugin with Client Credentials flow

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, token, endpoint, kong

Using Kong API Gateway, I have added the OAuth2 plugin to all API's in the hopes of getting one token to access these API's.

When I call: *www.example.com/oauth2/token* with the required fields:
`grant type`, `client id` and `client secret`

it forces me to add the API: *www.example.com/apiendpoint/oauth2/token*

Unfortunately the token generated only has access to the specific API.

I've tried:

```
www.example.com/apis/oauth2/token
www.example.com/token
```

As well as reviewing the latest API Dos:
https://getkong.org/docs/0.10.x/admin-api/
none of which worked.

Is it possible to generate one token to access all the API's and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with Kong today - you are welcome to open an issue https://github.com/Mashape/kong/issues to raise the visibility of your request with the Kong community.

Comment: Cheers Cooper. I managed to get around it by installing the key-auth plugin to all API and the acl plugin to individual endpoints. It seems to work nicely as one key can access multiple API's depending on the acl group.

Answer (score 0):

For people searching how to do this.

A way to achieve what was asked is by doing a post on the admin API:

```
$ curl -X POST http://kong:8001/oauth2_tokens \
    --data "api_id=API-ID" \
    --data "scope=SOME-SCOPE" \
    --data "credential_id=KONG-APPLICATION-ID" \
    --data "token_type=bearer" \
    --data "access_token=SOME-TOKEN" \
    --data "refresh_token=SOME-TOKEN" \
    --data "expires_in=3600"
```

This way you can set a token in the desired APIs.

The `KONG-APPLICATION-ID` can be found in the /consumers/*consumername*/oauth2 API point.

Comment: This should work but it is rather a way of hacking since it overwrites all Kong generated tokens for every involved API.

Comment: I`m using this metod and the existing tokens remain the same.